# TableLayout appearing on top of another TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following definition:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/leftContainer"
    android:layout_weight="0.8">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/drinksTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:padding="0dp" />
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemsTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Both table layouts are built programatically.

I want the second table to appear directly beneath the first table, however the best I can do is get it to sit at the bottom of the layout which I don't like (using alignParentBottom).

How can I have the `itemsTable` appear directly beneath the `drinksTable`?

Comment: I'd use a vertical `LinearLayout`. How do you want them set up, exactly? Half-and-half? One larger than the other? Scrolling? And what's the parent of the `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Hey Eric, the parent is a linear layout. The screen is split in half vertically with this relative layout filling the left hand 50% of the screen. I would like the second table to appear beneath the first, as the number of items in the first table is variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert your layout to a `LinearLayout`, making sure to add `android:orientation="vertical"`; this will make each element stack vertically.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/leftContainer"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/drinksTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:padding="0dp" />
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemsTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note, however, that if the number of elements is too great, they will flow off the screen at the bottom. (You may want to wrap this `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView`.)

Comment: Thanks Eric! Appreciate your help.